# Different ways to export Powershell information

Tags: powershell, printing, export

I have been using a PowerShell code that I wrote to pull AD groups with their name, description, members and info. For some reason, whether I use an output header format with -Append at the end or Export-CSV -notypeinformation, both ways won't hold the long info fields that my AD groups have. The info is so long that it prints on a different line(one extra line or many) which makes the long list of 16,000 groups messed up. Instead of each line (when I export it to excel) being on their own line, practically almost all of them are on multiple lines. This gets crazy when I have to manual fix all of them practically.

So my question is, how can I keep all the data in the "info" field in one cell?

The codes that I used (parts of my code) is as follows:

I make a header format of:

```
Header = `
"Group ID Name" + "|" + `
"Description" + "|" + `
"Notes Field" + " |" + "Members" + "|" + "Member Count"


#Write out the header
$Header | Out-File $pathALL -Append
```

with the export code of:

```
$listing =`
$empty.Name + "|" + `
$empty.Description + "|" + `
$empty.info + "|" + `
$members 
$listing | Out-File $pathALL -Append
```

This still messed up the info field because apparently there is too much information to fit in the cell. So I tried:

```
$emptys = get-adgroup -properties name, description, info -filter {name -like "AP*"} `
| Select name, description, info | Export-CSV "C:\Temp\groupsALL.txt"  -notypeinformation
```

This print version still did the same issue and separating all the data was harder this way too. In this situation, how can I fit it all into one cell or at the very least print the rest of the information **in the next adjacent cell**?

**QUESTION ANSWERED: MY INFO FIELD HAD NEW LINES SO I ADDED A FOREACH:**

```
foreach ($lines in $emptys.info){

$lines -replace "``n","" 

}
```

AND CHANGED MY PRINT TO:

```
$listing =`
$empty.Name + "|" + `
$empty.Description + "|" + `
#$empty.Info + "|" + `
$lines + "|" + `
$members
```

Comment: Is it a matter of a field being too long, or are there line breaks in your data? If there are line break, just replace them with another character before outputting to a file.

Comment: Actually... my info field has information with multiple different lines. Haven't heard yet about a way to remove them... hmm will look into it

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I found out a way to fix it!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$listing =`
$empty.Name + "|" + `
$empty.Description + "|" + `
$empty.info -replace "`r`n", "NewLine" + "|" + `
$members 
$listing | Out-File $pathALL -Append
```

Obviously replace "NewLine" in the 4th line above with whatever you want in place of the newlines.

Comment: I fixed my question before I saw this right here. Thanks for the comment about line breaks. Never would have thought about that.